# The sum of the greatest 3-digit number and the smallest 4-digit number is???

Tags: arithmetic

Options:
A) 1999
B)  999
C) 1099
D) 109
How's it done?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: What is the greatest three-digit number? What is the smallest four-digit number?

Then, add them.